# connect to documentdb from Java from localhost with a ssh tunnel

Tags: java, aws-documentdb

I'm trying to connect to a Remote DocumentDB instance from Java Code from local PC using ssh Tunnel on Windows.

Using 2 terms :
One with:

```
ssh -L 27017:my-cluster.eu-west-3.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 ubuntu@my-ec2.com -N
```

And an other:

```
mongosh --sslAllowInvalidHostnames --ssl --sslCAFile rds-ca.pem --username user --password pwd
```

It works correctly.

Now I'm trying to connect through my Java program:
I followed the aws documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html

But have error :

```
An error occurred on mongodb connection: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@3e6104fc. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}, caused by {sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}, caused by {sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}}]
```

My Java program is built with Intelliji Idea and I use

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the DocumentDB URI used when connecting from Java? You can't connect in replica set mode via ssh tunnel, you'll have to remove replicaSet=rs0 and add directConnection=true

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Changed for atlas ...